# Reorder columns in reverse order

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a list of flex items within a flexbox. The order of the items matter, and for accessibility purposes, the items need to show up in the correct order in the dom.

[[itema][itemb][itemc]]

When the flexbox shrinks I would like to have the items wrap in reverse order, e.g. itema wraps first, etc. Is there any way to have the itema wrap first? Thanks!

Edit:

Here is the code

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">item1</div>
        <div class="item orange">item2</div>
        <div class="item blue">item3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="last-item green">menu</div>
</div>

.flex {
    display: flex;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.last-item {
    width: 40px;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    height: 80px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckek3ehk/4/)

All the behavior is as desired except I want the first item to wrap first. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please expand your question with the result as it is now, the desired result, and the code you've used.

Comment: What does "wraps first" mean? Can you provide an image?

Comment: Sorry about that. It means that item1 would overflow first.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `flex-direction: column-reverse` to get your solution.

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .flex-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
.first,
.second,
.third {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-box">
  <div class="first">
    <p>First Box</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <p>Second Box</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    <p>Third Box</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/rf6qh31d/embedded/result/)

Comment: Make sure that you catch all the prefixes. `display: flex` turns into `-webkit-flex`, `-webkit-box`, `-ms-flexbox`, `flex`. Column reversal: `flex-direction: column`, `-webkit-flex-direction: column`, `-webkit-box-orient: vertical`

Comment: It's ridiculous, really. I say we make a new standard, and make the rest of the browsers follow! `display: flexbox` and `flexbox-direction: column-reverse`!

Comment: Thanks, Manoj. Your solution reverses the order when the viewport reaches a size but the items wraps in the normal order e.g. the item on the far right wraps first. I need the items to wrap in reverse order, so I need the first item to wrap first, followed by second, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To make item1 wrap first, you can use `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse` on your flex container.

Try this simplified version of you code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">item1</div>
    <div class="item orange">item2</div>
    <div class="item blue">item3</div>
</div>

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.item {
    background-color: red;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue
}
```

See the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) for browser support.